# Why do I need to add an out parameter to my output bindings?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Suppose I have this signature for my Azure Function:

```
   [FunctionName("DoStuff")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
        TraceWriter log,
        [Queue("output-queue")] string outputQueue)
    {
    }
```

This method only works for me if I add an `out` parameter to the output binding, `outputQueue`. I'm using VS 2017.3.2

The Microsoft examples DO NOT use the `out` parameter. Why do I need to add the `out` parameter?

Comment: So how did you make it work? To which class do you instantiate the `out` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation which you are referring might be old.

Here is why out is needed.

I want to pass set of inputs to function, (Multiple Triggers) and set of outputs from a function (Send data to Queue, Output Reference of completion)

We need an indication what needs to be passed and what needs to be sent out of the function.

function(Class1 i, Class2 j, out Class3 k, out Class4 l) {

}

out refers to the reference of the object that is sending out of function and does not need deserialization of the object during the call.

while i and j in the above needs deserialization, while Class3 and Class4 are not.

There need to be extra cycle need to determine the mapping and auto recognize whether it is in or out parameters.

Having an 'out' make the process simple and helps to execute the code quicker.

Comment: Your explanation would be correct, but not for `IAsyncCollector` type. That one makes no sense for input bindings.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use 'out' when your function is doing an assignment to one of the parameters. For example if your parameter is a string, or a byte[], or a poco, you'll need to do an assignment.

Here's one example from the documentation where out is required:

```
#load "..\shared\order.csx"

using System;

public static void Run(Order myQueueItem, out Order outputQueueItem,TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed order...");
    log.Info(myQueueItem.ToString());

    outputQueueItem = myQueueItem;
}
```

You don't need to use out if your function is calling methods on the parameter. Stream, ICollector and IAsyncCollector all fall in this category. Here are two examples:

```
public async static Task ProcessQueueMessageAsync(
        string blobName,
        Stream blobInput,
        Stream blobOutput)
{
    await blobInput.CopyToAsync(blobOutput, 4096, token);
}
```

And:

```
#load "..\shared\order.csx"

using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(Order req, IAsyncCollector<Order> outputQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function received an order.");
    log.Info(req.ToString());
    log.Info("Submitting to processing queue.");

    if (req.orderId == null)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    else
    {
        await outputQueueItem.AddAsync(req);
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

You mentioned that your example code had a problem with your IAsyncCollector parameter. As mentioned by others, it looks like the problem is you're missing your `[Queue(..)]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are rather missing an attribute to denote the type of your output binding. For instance, if you want to use a Storage Queue, declare your function as

```cs
[FunctionName("DoStuff")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
    TraceWriter log,
    [Queue("my-out-queue")] IAsyncCollector<DetailInfo> outputQueue)
{
}
```